# JSON.API Failed to fetch

Tags: 9

I am trying to set up a React component that will fetch the JSON from my Drupal 9 site using JSON:API and JSON:API Views module.

I can see the JSON when I visit the URL, but get 'failed to fetch' from the React component.

What is the problem?

```js
const endpoint = "http://my_site.com/jsonapi/views/job_listings/page_2";
const Job_Board = () => { const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const data = await fetch(endpoint).then((res) => res.json());
    setUsers(data);
  })();
}, []);
```

Comment: If Drupal's output is correct, but React is failing, then this question belongs on Stack Overflow, not here.  Generally speaking, try using Postman to make the request; if Postman works but fetch() doesn't, you're definitely using fetch() wrong.  Also, consider using a library that has built-in error handling like `axios` instead of fetch.

Comment: Postman GET works fine

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set CORS headers for the Drupal site. I did this with https://www.drupal.org/project/cors_ui

I just set allowed headers, methods, and origins to *